# Safari no getting jquery click function

Tags: jquery, safari, hyperlink, click

I have:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mydiv").click(function(){

       $("#content").load("html/page.php");

    });
});

</script>
```

And inside of an image map:

```
<div id="mydiv"><area shape="rect" coords="318,122,413,221" href="#"/></div>
```

Another version of the line before:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="318,122,413,221" href="#" id="mydiv"/>
```

These (both versions of the image map line) work in all my browsers but in Safari (5.0.5). When in Safari I click but nothing happens. A regular link works so there's nothing wrong with the image map.

I've tried deleting the # in href, and then it works for Safari but not for the rest. If I delete the whole href="#" what happens is that I go back to not working in Safari and working for the rest

Anyone have an idea on what to do for the click to work in all browsers?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am having the same issue, Safari doesn't appear to fire a jquery click event when it's on an <area> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't fix your problem, but you might want to change `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` to `$(function(){`. It does exactly the same thing.

Regarding your problem, have you tried stepping through with the [debugger](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html)? This will help you find out if the click handler is being triggered.

If it's the contents of the href attribute causing problems, you could try putting "/" in rather than "#"? Obviously, this will give different behaviour when JavaScript is disabled. What do you want to happen when JS is disabled?

Also, [area](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Area) must have an ancestor map element. Does it?

It might help if you bind the click handler to the area itself, rather than its parent.

Comment: thanks for answering. Cannot use /, goes back to the root folder :(

Comment: What about the other suggestions?

Comment: been using the event listener, but there's none listed, not even when I clik on the map .. Also been using the noref element listed in the area element .. but cannot make it work

Comment: Try adding the listener to the area element rather than the div. I think that's the most likely problem.